# Show the screenshot as a GUI texture2d after saving it

Tags: c#, android, ios, unity-game-engine

I am making a simple application that have two scenes the 1st one have an AR camera that i will take a screenshot and save it. and the 2nd scene it just will show me a GUI with the screenshot picture that had been captured.

the application do take the screenshot and save it with deferent names and everything is fine my problem that i couldn't show the image after i capture it in the 2nd scene.

i am using a 3 scripts

1st one is sceneManager that i used to store a static variable to save the screenshot name to be used in the two scenes :

```
   using UnityEngine;
   using System.Collections;

    public class sceneManeger : MonoBehaviour {

        #region STATIC VARIABLES
        public static string fileName;
        #endregion

    }
```

the 2nd script is screenshot.cs

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class screenshot : MonoBehaviour {

    public static string filename;
    public Texture2D icon;

    void Start () {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    }

    void OnGUI() {

        if (GUI.Button (new Rect (Screen.width / 2, Screen.height - 100, 60, 60), icon, "lable")) {

            Application.CaptureScreenshot("Screenshot" + System.DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm-ss") + ".png");
            filename = "Screenshot" + System.DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm-ss") + ".png" ;
            sceneManeger.fileName = filename;

            Application.LoadLevel("normal");

        }

    }

}
```

3d one is GUIscreenshot.cs  that i want to use it to show the capture image :

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class GUIscreenShot : MonoBehaviour {

    public Texture2D img;

    private string path;

    void Start () {

        }

    void Update () {

    }

    void OnGUI () {

        if  (GUI.Button (new Rect(0, 0, Screen.width, Screen.height),img, "lable")) {
            Application.LoadLevel("AS");        

        }
    }
}
```

i need to know how to store the screenshot that had been capture in the texture2d img variable so it will render as a GUI texture

ok i change my app to just one scene like this screenShot.cs :

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class screenshot : MonoBehaviour {

    public static string filename;
    public Texture2D icon;
    private Texture2D imgcap;
    public bool showBox = false;

    void Start () {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {


    }


    void OnGUI() {

        if (showBox) {

            GUI.Button (new Rect (0, 0, Screen.width, Screen.height), imgcap, "lable");

        }

        if (GUI.Button (new Rect (Screen.width / 2, Screen.height - 100, 60, 60), icon, "lable")) {

            Application.CaptureScreenshot("Screenshot" + System.DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm-ss") + ".png");
            filename = "Screenshot" + System.DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm-ss") + ".png" ;

            imgcap = Resources.Load(filename) as Texture2D;

            showBox = true;



        }

    }

}
```

but it still not working , when i press the GUI button to get the screen shot it wont show the anothere GUI that should show the image that had been taking.

Comment: I believe you've already saved the screen shot in the application? You don't know how to retrieve it and use it as a texture for your GUI?

Comment: yes thats exactly my problem , the screen shot is saved but how can i retrieve it and use it as a texture for my GUI ?

Comment: Ok well are you trying to display several screenshots or only 1 at a time after you've taken it?

Comment: i just need to display one , i have a GUI button that after i press it , it will take a screen shot and save it and i want to display this screen shot to the user so he can see what did he capture

Comment: Ok... You could create a "Texture2D currentScreenShot" in the screenshot class and set that variable by using "Resources.Load('name of most recent screenshot') once the button has been pressed... Then in your Guiscreenshot class get that variable and display it like any other Gui texture

Comment: ok thnx for your  replay i will try that and tell you how its goes

Comment: I edited my question, I change my app to just one scene as showing up, please check it and tell me whats wrong, thank you so much

Comment: Ok so now you've loaded the image you need to access that image in your gui class...

Comment: how do i do that ??? can you help me with that please

Comment: The simplest way would be to change the "Texture2D imgcap" to static like so "Public static Texture2D imgcap" and access it in your GUIscreenshot class like this: "Texture2D imgToDisplay = screenshot.imgcap"... Do you understand? You need to learn the basics of Object Oriented Programming... This is basic stuff that you should already know

Comment: ya i get that, thanx i am rely new to c# programming but i am learning fast i will try that and tell you what happen .